# How to disable suggestions opening by default with geocode.earth ge-autocomplete widget when "value" provided

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, geocode

Trying to use the Geocode.earth web component: https://geocode.earth/docs/components/autocomplete-element/

If one provides a default value, the autocomplete suggestions opens by default on page load. I would like to disable this, but don't see a way.

`<ge-autocomplete value="Something"></ge-autocomplete>`